# Logical expression problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

How can I solve this?

$ \varphi = (\neg x_1 \lor \neg x_2 \lor \neg x_3)\land(\neg x_2 \lor \neg x_3 \lor \neg x_4)\land(\neg x_3 \lor \neg x_4 \lor \neg x_1)\land(\neg x_4 \lor \neg x_1 \lor \neg x_2)\land(x_1 \lor x_2)\land(x_2 \lor x_3)\land(x_3 \lor x_4)\land(x_4 \lor x_1).$

Also write $\varphi$ as $\varphi(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$.
Give an interpretation of $\varphi$ in English. What does $\varphi$ compute? Explain and justify your answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I made a truth table and ended up with 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0. I'm guessing I need to think of a logically equivalent circuit that computes the same?

Answer (score 0):

If we put the $4$ different variables $x_i$ variables in a circle, then the last four terms express that for any two 'neighboring' variables, at least one of them is 'true' or 'on' (or a $1$, if that's what you prefer), but the first four terms specify that out of ever three successive ones, at least one must be false.

So note: if you have two neighboring ones being both 'true' ('on'), then on either side of them there must be a 'false' ('off') one (e.g. if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both true, then $x_3$ and $x_4$ must both be false). However, those other two are neighbors in the circle themselves, and so we have a problem, since out of any two neighboring ones there must at least be one true one.

So, this tells us that you cannot have two true ones being next to each other ... and hence for any two neighboring ones, one must also be true and one must be false. Hence, the values must alternate going around the circle: either $x_1=True$, $x_2=False$, $x_3=True$, and $x_4=False$, or $x_1=False$, $x_2=True$, $x_3=False$, and $x_4=True$.  I assume that reflects the two $1$'s that you found in your truth-table as well ... so that's probably not news to you.

However, with the above analysis, I think you do reach a more conceptual 'picture' of what the function is computing: it is effectively true if and only if the values are alternating (again, assuming an order of $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ and then possibly circling back to $x_1$) ... and that makes for a nice and concise English description/interpretation... which is what the question was asking for.